# pjax change history without making an actual request / use pjax without connecting to server

Tags: jquery, ajax, pjax

I am using pjax and I understand how it works. I handle all pjax logic with JS and in some cases I want to "fake" a new pageload without pjax actually fetching any data.

My question is, how can I set a new history-entry with pjax without pjax actually connecting to the server? Basically use pjax as usual, but without connecting to the server.

I know this is not the actual purpose or use of pjax, but I don't want to load history.js or something similar just for this small exception of mine. In theory this should be handled by pjax just as well...

Answer (score 1):

Try just using `history.pushState()`. `history` is a builtin HTML5 feature that allows you to add a new history entry without reloading the page. Because calling that function doesn't actually fire a popstate event, pjax should not be effected.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I'll give it a try and report back tomorrow or so :)

Comment: Sure. If it works out, make sure you accept whichever answer works.

Comment: So far I have figured most stuff out. Your hint pushed me in the right direction, thanks again! Anyways I encountered an issue using `pjax` and `history.pushState` separately: I also have `function`s with `pjax:popstate`, so when I use `history.pushState()` seperatly the functions don't get triggered by `pjax:popstate`.. So it really would be helpful if I could only use `pjax` as stated.

Comment: It might work that I also listen for `history.popState()` separately as well, so I would be doing both.. I'll be trying around :)

Comment: Okay, it turns out I have to do it with `pjax` as that handles caching as well, while setting it manually I would not have such thing.

Comment: thank you for your input, in the end I took a bigger look on `history.pushState`. It does not really solve my issue, but I learned something new along the way. Have a bounty ;)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using **history.replaceState(newUrl)**, otherwise, if you use history.pushState(newUrl), you should also handle "back button" event properly. Please also see in which browsers this is supported http://caniuse.com/#search=pushstate. Also take into account, that in some browsers it will not work in fullscreen mode due to security reasons.

I recommend to write your own function like:

```
var historyChangeState = function (newUrl) {
    history.replaceState(newUrl)
    // something else to manage
}
```

so you will be able to tweak it in the future.

Comment: Although I will not be using the replaceState per se I like the idea with the separat function handling the logic. Anyways thanks for your answer...